# Tiling the concave polygons with non-polygons

Tags: polygons, tiling, plane-geometry

Suppose that we reside in the set of all concave polygons (that is, polygons which are non-convex and simple, simple means that the boundary of the polygon does not cross itself).

Let us denote that set as $C$

The question is:

> Does there exist $n_0 \in  \mathbb N \setminus \{1,2\}$ and some concave polygon $p \in C$ such that $p$ can be tiled with $n_0$ congruent connected parts which are not polygons?

Comment: It might help our understanding of your question if you told us why you have excluded $n_0 = 2$.

Comment: @RobArthan Hey Rob, it is because I have some vague feeling that it maybe could be done for $n_0=2$, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Do you require polygons to have straight line segments for their edges?

Comment: @RobArthan Yes.

Comment: And a finite number of them, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a regular $n$-gon with centre $O$ and vertices $V_1, \ldots, V_n$ and draw a curvilinear arc $R_1$ from $O$ to $V_1$ that lies in the interior of $\triangle O V_1 V_2$. Now rotate $R_1$ through $2\pi k/n$ for $k = 1, 2, \ldots n - 1$, giving arcs $R_2, \ldots R_n$. This gives you $n$ congruent "curvilinear triangles" that tile the $n$-gon.

This [image](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=camera+iris+image&client=safari&rls=en&tbm=isch&imgil=8_tLjUY8l5Jo2M%253A%253BMmJq9YDuShyTZM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Farchive.wtsp.com%25252Fslideshows%25252F2011%25252Fgallery.aspx%25253Fslideshowname%2525253DCBS-Eye-Evolution%25252526N%2525253D2&source=iu&pf=m&fir=8_tLjUY8l5Jo2M%253A%252CMmJq9YDuShyTZM%252C_&biw=1213&bih=614&usg=__3SWO4a_7PYX8rT0OH2PA6xdZgSY%3D&ved=0CDUQyjdqFQoTCO2WpaTJjskCFUUyGgodhcsJmA&ei=2nRGVu3BF8XkaIWXp8AJ#imgrc=8_tLjUY8l5Jo2M%3A&usg=__3SWO4a_7PYX8rT0OH2PA6xdZgSY%3D) of a camera iris gives the idea much better than the above words.

To exhibit a similar tiling for a non-convex polygon, carry out the above construction for the polygon comprising the union of two regular $n$-gons with $n > 4$ that have a common edge (like two adjacent cells in a honeycomb). The boundary of the union is a non-convex simple polygon that can be tiled by the congruent non-polygons described above,

Comment: But those triangles overlap in a sense that they all have centre $C$ as they common point, and tiling is by definition composed of non-overlapping pieces, is it?

Comment: No. The definition of a tiling requires that the tiles only intersect on their boundaries (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation).

Comment: Okay, but still regular n-gon is convex and the question is about concave polygons?

Comment: See the revised answer.

Comment: If we take a non-convex polygon which is union of two regular n-gons that share an edge, then is that non-convex polygon simple? It seems to me that it is not because it has a boundary that crosses itself?

Comment: I mean, we cannot draw him and go through every point just once, right?

Comment: The boundary of the union of these two non-convex polygons comprises a simple polygon. That simple polygon is tiled by the non-polygons described in my answer.

Comment: My pleasure. I have tried to clarify the last part of the answer.

Comment: Note that another simple version of this is that you can tile any 'star polygon' - such as the interior of the pentagram (the purple area in https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_6zrdK5O_LIg/TWAfi_JT3MI/AAAAAAAABjI/zdDjUt15JGQ/pentagram_arrowed.png ) by a tiling that connects each of the 'inside' vertices in symmetric curved fashion to the centerpoint of the polygon.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I don't see how that works.

Comment: @RobArthan Label the vertices of the star as 1..10 in clockwise order, so that 1,3,5,7,9 are the vertices at the 'points' of the star, and 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 are the interior (concave) vertices.  Now, draw your favorite curved line from the center of the star to vertex 2, and just as in Rob's answer use the symmetry to draw a similar line to vertices 4, 6, 8, 10.  This will chop the star into five congruent pieces

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: got it. Thanks!